# Populating bootbox.js prompt with django context data

Tags: python, jquery, django, bootbox

What i'm trying to do is get the `text`value in the prompt to match with the data being received from the view. The bootbox.js looks like this:

```
<script>
$('#playGameBtn').click(function(){
  bootbox.prompt({
    title: "Please select players for this match",
    value: ['1', '3'],
    inputType: 'checkbox',

    inputOptions: [{
        text: '{{standing.player_name}}',
        value: '1',
    },
    {
        text: 'Choice Two',
        value: '2',
    },
    {
        text: 'Choice Three',
        value: '3',
    }],
    callback: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});

}

)
</script>
```

What I have tried is this:

```
<script>
  {%for standing in standings%}
$('#playGameBtn').click(function(){
  bootbox.prompt({
    title: "Please select players for this match",
    value: ['1', '3'],
    inputType: 'checkbox',

    inputOptions: [{
        text: '{{standing.player_name}}',
        value: '1',
    },
    {
        text: 'Choice Two',
        value: '2',
    },
    {
        text: 'Choice Three',
        value: '3',
    }],
    callback: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});

}

)
{%endfor%}
</script>
```

But this just shows the same prompt multiple times with a different name each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop is creating same javascript for initializing `bootbox` again and again. You just have to loop for options. like this

```
<script>
  $('#playGameBtn').click(function () {
      bootbox.prompt({
        title: "Please select players for this match",
        value: ['1', '3'],
        inputType: 'checkbox',

        inputOptions: [
          {% for standing in standings %}
            {
              text: '{{standing.player_name}}',
              value: '{{ forloop.counter }}'
            },
          {% endfor %}
        ],
        callback: function (result) {
          console.log(result)
        }
      })

    }
  )
</script>
```